# Programmatically recording an Adword conversion

Tags: cookies, google-ads-api

We have a problem of visitor qualification in our Adword campaign. Concretely, often a visitor that has no clue about what the software we sell does, still *download trial* (despite our attempt to explain him what it does, on landing pages) and count as a +1 recorded conversion in our Adword stats. Since Adword seems intelligent enough to maximize the conversions#, it ends up bringing us plenty of non-qualified visitors. Thus we need to define what is a conversion differently, sometime after the *download trial* operation.

The option of defining conversion as a sale isn't good, because most of our users are professional employees. In such situation, most of the time the machine from where the product is purchased isn't the machine used for first download.

The best conversion definition I can think of, would be a first successful run of our product (what we call *evaluation*). Indeed, by tracking what happened, we already asserted that only qualified visitor/dowloader do evaluate our product properly, most of the time on the same machine used for downloading the trial bits.

Our product is a rich UI program developed with the .NET platform. To achieve *conversion recorded on evaluation*, we need to read programmatically all installed browsers cookies, (there is a free [libraries](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/330142/Cookie-Quest-A-Quest-to-Read-Cookies-from-Four-Pop) for that) and if we find a **Adword Conversion Tracking cookie** corresponding to our product, we can:

- Launch the concerned browser programmatically on a *Thanks for evaluating our product page* that contains the Adword conversion javascript (*in-browser* scenario).
- or, better if possible, ping back programmatically the Adword server with data found in the cookie (*out-of-browser* scenario).

I'm not an expert on these technologies so I might be well missing something. Despite a lot of searches on the web I didn't find any valuable resource on such scenario. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Rachel, didn't heard about google-adword-API before, even available for .NET, wow! Thanks for adding a tag to this technology. Seems you are pointing out to the right direction, maybe someone can answer my problematic with this API :)